# How can I format Unicode strings properly?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, string-formatting

When I try to centralizer a Unicode string in python with the align functionality of `str.format()`, I get wrong results. For example I want to underline a string and then want to center it.

```
underline_txt = ''.join(map(lambda x: x + '\u0332', 'AB'))
centered_txt = '{:^4}'.format(underline_txt)
print(centered_txt)
```

The problem is that the `centered_txt` is 4 characters long, but the printed output is 2 terminal cells wide. Since `x + '\u0332'`is one terminal cell wide.

Now my question: How can I format Unicode strings properly?

I could solve the problem by padding the string by hand, but I wanted to know if there is a more general solution.
Quick and dirty solution, which has a problem if `len(underline_txt) == 0` and when other combination characters are used like tilde ('\u0303').

```
str_len = len(underline_txt) / 4 
left_pad, right_pad = ' ' * math.floor(str_len), ' ' * math.ceil(str_len)
really_centered = left_pad + centered_txt + right_hand
```

Comment: Resource requests are off topic on Stack Overflow, but you might find [wcwidth](https://github.com/jquast/wcwidth) or [blessed](https://github.com/jquast/blessed) (which uses wcwidth) helpful.

Comment: To nitpick slightly, by the way: the string in question is four characters in length (strings don't have a length in bytes; only encodings of them do), and two terminal character cells wide. It's easy to confuse yourself if you don't stick to the correct terminology. For instance, `'敚潲倠物敡獵'` is six characters long, twelve terminal character cells wide, and its UTF-8 encoding has 18 bytes.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Or, 4 code points and 2 user-perceived characters (approx. grapheme clusters).

Comment: @IljaEverilä in this case it's cells rather than graphemes that matter. Consider the string in my previous comment and how to correctly center it in a terminal display, for example. Of course, you're right to correct me on "code points" vs. "characters" :-)

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Sorry, for asking for a module. Would it be ok if I changed the question to "Is there a way in which i can format Unicode strings, properly?". Or is it in general out of scope?

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Is there a reference for these terms? (like terminal character cells)

Comment: I've retracted the close vote; to be honest though I think you *are* better off with a third-party library than trying to solve the problem yourself, because the interaction between console displays and Unicode combining characters, full-width characters etc. will have subtleties best addressed in such a library. As for references, there's the [Unicode glossary](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/), but that's bulky and focuses on Unicode itself, rather than terminal display issues. "Terminal character cell" is more a sensible description rather than a defined term, and I think self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by creating my own `string.Formatter` in which I override the method `format_field(self, value, format_spec)`. In format_field I check if the given `value` is an instance of `str` and it printed length differs from its character length. Only then I do a "Unicode alignment". The parsing of the `format_spec` is a python implementation of the `format(value, format_spec)` built-in and it tries to mimic all its edge cases.

```
import wcwidth

class UnicodeFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, format_spec):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            # If `value` is not a string use format built-in
            return format(value, format_spec)
        if format_spec == '':
            # If `format_spec` is empty we just return the `value` string
            return value

        print_length = wcwidth.wcswidth(value)
        if len(value) == print_length:
            return format(value, format_spec)

        fill, align, width, format_spec = UnicodeFormatter.parse_align(format_spec)
        if width == 0:
            return value
        formatted_value = format(value, format_spec)
        pad_len = width - print_length
        if pad_len <= 0:
            return formatted_value
        left_pad = ''
        right_pad = ''
        if align in '<=':
            right_pad = fill * pad_len
        elif align == '>':
            left_pad = fill * pad_len
        elif align == '^':
            left_pad = fill * math.floor(pad_len/2)
            right_pad = fill * math.ceil(pad_len/2)
        return ''.join((left_pad, formatted_value, right_pad))

    @staticmethod
    def parse_align(format_spec):
        format_chars = '=<>^'
        align = '<'
        fill = None
        if format_spec[1] in format_chars:
            align = format_spec[1]
            fill = format_spec[0]
            format_spec = format_spec[2:]
        elif format_spec[0] in format_chars:
            align = format_spec[0]
            format_spec = format_spec[1:]

        if align == '=':
            raise ValueError("'=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier")
        if format_spec[0] in '+- ':
            raise ValueError('Sign not allowed in string format specifier')
        if format_spec[0] == '#':
            raise ValueError('Alternate form (#) not allowed in string format specifier')
        if format_spec[0] == '0':
            if fill is None:
                fill = '0'
            format_spec = format_spec[1:]
        if fill is None:
            fill = ' '
        width_str = ''.join(itertools.takewhile(str.isdigit, format_spec))
        width_len = len(width_str)
        format_spec = format_spec[width_len:]
        if width_len > 0:
            width = int(width_str)
        else:
            width = 0
        return fill, align, width, format_spec
```